# How to set custom tone for message alert of a single contact?

Tags: android

I need to set a tone as message alert from my sdcard, to a specific contact in my phone contacts. I tried using this,

```
 RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                            GCMController.aController,
                            RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION,
                            newUri);
```

But, it sets the notification tone in the settings of my phone, which sets the tone for all incoming sms and calls.
I want the change of SMS(message) alert to be reflected in the contacts(which has message alert field) for a single person.
Am able to do the same for ringtones using below code but not for message alert.

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops1 = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
                ops1.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withSelection(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID + "=?", args)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Contacts.CUSTOM_RINGTONE,newUri.toString()).build());
```

can anyone please help me solve this issue.? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for the same thing, but looking at ContactsContract.class, it seem like there is no such option. The only logical place to but it would be here I guess. I guess we are out of luck :(

```
protected static interface ContactOptionsColumns {
    java.lang.String TIMES_CONTACTED = "times_contacted";
    java.lang.String LAST_TIME_CONTACTED = "last_time_contacted";
    java.lang.String STARRED = "starred";
    java.lang.String CUSTOM_RINGTONE = "custom_ringtone";
    java.lang.String SEND_TO_VOICEMAIL = "send_to_voicemail";
}
```